# cleanest way to set up table cells to highlight color when checkbox selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to create an html table that will display a color-coded broadcast schedule containing different types of programs. For example, at noon on Monday, we will broadcast something in the "sports" category. The table will be 7 days across and 1 row per hour of day. Empty cells are just white.

I will hand code the table, so I will be able to use css to identify the table cells with the category. So maybe this is like High School Football Game

Below the table, I will display the categories with checkboxes next to them. When a user clicks the checkbox, I want all cells in the table that have been coded with that class to turn "on"--meaning they change color from a default, non-highlighted color to a brighter color. Pale yellow becomes bright yellow, etc.

basic html would look like this:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>11am</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<td>12 noon</td>
<td>High School Football game</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<td>1pm</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
<input type="checkbox">Sports</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0b7c8tw0/) from where you could proceed. I've added the name `sports` to the checkbox, a class `sports` to the `<td>` and added a class `.active` with a background color. Following jquery

```
$("input[name='sports']").on("click", function () {
 $(".sports").toggleClass("active");
});
```

toggles the class `active` on each click. You can add checking for the input `checked` state instead of just changing on each click.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

You must add a flag to your element in the table to highlight them. A custum attribute or a class will do the trick.

```
<td data-type="sports" >High School Football game</td>
<input type="checkbox">Sports</input>

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked)
    {
        $("[data-type='"+ $(this).val() +"']).addClass("yellowhighlight");
    }
    else
    {
        $("[data-type='"+ $(this).val() +"']).removeClass("yellowhighlight");

    }

});
```

And the css

```
.yellowhighlight
{
    border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

Code not tested but i hope you get the idea.